# Trying to pass a student key from a html form to a php file to scan a database

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

Basicaly having issues setting up a webpage which will taken in a student key entered by the user. This will then parse the student key to another file which will run it against a mysql backend to see what records this student already has. But can not get it working for the life of me please help I'm still a newb at this.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("support_log", $con);


  $result= mysql_query("SELECT student.first_name, student.surname, student.year_group, student.STKEY, student_log.issue
        FROM `student` JOIN `student_log`
        WHERE student.STKEY like '$_POST[stkey]'");

  $result2 = mysql_query($result) or die("Error: " . mysql_error()); 
  if(mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0){ 
  echo("no records found"); 
  } ELSE { 

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Year Group</th>
    <th>Student Key</th>
    <th>Issue</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['First_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['year_group'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['stkey'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['issue'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
  }
  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

After changing my where statement to:

```
  WHERE student.STKEY like '$_POST[stkey]'");
```

I am no longer reciving errors from PHP but now recieving the error Query was empty which is part of my code to detect if there is no results. Though I have tested that query in phpmyadmin and it spits out results. From looking at the code does anyone have any solutions? I have also checked the parse by running an echo on the post command to ensure the data being entered was correct.

Edit: Got rid of the whole result2 check now throwing a:
 Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\stkey_submit.php on line 24

Answer (score 1):

Try `$_POST['stkey']` instead of `$_POST[stkey]`

EDIT : if you use it in a query, it would be preferable to do :

```
$stkey = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stkey']);
$sql = "SELECT ....... like '$stkey'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: returns with Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\wamp\www\stkey_submit.php on line 13

Comment: It's because you can't use it the way you do. Look at the edit I did on my message.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT student.first_name, student.surname, student.year_group, student.STKEY, student_log.issue
    FROM `student` JOIN `student_log`
    WHERE student.STKEY like " . $_POST["stkey"]);
```

Comment: It's now returning Error: No Query Found which is part of the code further down even though there is correct data in the database. Is there something else that could be stuffing it up?

Comment: the table name is student the first_name is the name of the column. Thought I might need it as using a JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the value of stkey on a variable before including it on the query?

```
$stkey = $_POST['stkey'];
$result= mysql_query("SELECT student.first_name, student.surname, 
        student.year_group, student.STKEY, student_log.issue
        FROM `student` JOIN `student_log`
        WHERE student.STKEY LIKE '%$stkey%'");
```

You might also want to use MySqli or PDO instead of the MySql database API. Take a look at this post from Nettuts: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/